# Cannot convert error while overloading * operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a DynamicArrayIterator class like this

```
template <class T> class DynamicArrayIterator{
private:
    int currentPosition;
    DynamicArray<T>* array; //pointer to the dynamic array
    int direction; //1 indicates forward, -1 indicates backwards  
public:
    DynamicArrayIterator(DynamicArray<T>* dyn, int pos, int dir){
    array = dyn;
    currentPosition = pos;
    direction = dir;
    }
    T operator *(){
    T t = array[currentPosition];
    return t;
    }
    void operator ++(){
    this->currentPosition += this->direction;
    }
```

The DynamicArray class is set up as

```
template <class T> class DynamicArray{

private:
    T *storage;
    int cur; //next position available
    int max; //capacity
public:
    DynamicArray(); //constructor
    ~DynamicArray(); //destructor
    void add(T item);
    T remove(int i);
    int size();

/*20*/  T& operator [](int i){ //selected if object called on is not const
    return storage[i];
    }
    T operator [](int i)const{ //selected if called by a const object
    return storage[i];
    }
    DynamicArrayIterator<T> begin(){
    return DynamicArrayIterator<T>(this, 0, 1);
    }
    DynamicArrayIterator<T> end(){
    return DynamicArrayIterator<T>(this, this->cur, 1);
    }
    DynamicArrayIterator<T> r_begin(){
    return DynamicArrayIterator<T>(this, 0, -1);
    }
    DynamicArrayIterator<T> r_end(){
    return DynamicArrayIterator<T>(this, this->cur, -1);
    }
};
```

I am having trouble with overloading the * operator; I would like to be able to directly get and set values with it; I call it like this:

```
int main(){
    DynamicArray<int> foo;
    foo.add(3);
    foo.add(2);
    cout << foo[1] << endl;
    foo[1] = 10;
    cout << foo[1] << endl;
    DynamicArrayIterator<int> a = foo.begin();
    ++a;
    cout << *a << endl;
}
```

and receive the error

```
DynamicArray.cpp:98:29: error: cannot convert ‘DynamicArray<int>’ to ‘int’ in initialization
  T t = array[currentPosition];
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: *Where* do you get the error (please mark it out with e.g. a comment)? And what more does the compiler tell you (please edit your question to include the *complete* output, in *full* and *unedited*)?

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
T& operator *() { return (*array)[currentPosition]; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your iterator you have `DynamicArray<T>* array` which means `array` is a pointer to a `DynamicArray<T>`.  So with

```
T t = array[currentPosition];
```

You tell the compiler to return the `DynamicArray<T>` at position `array + currentPosition`.  You can't assign that to `t` since `t` is just an `int` and that is really not what you want since the pointer only points to a single `DynamicArray<T>`.

What you need is to dereference to pointer and then access the element like

```
T t = (*array)[currentPosition];
```

Really though you should return a reference so you can modify that element and that would look like

```
T& operator *() 
{ 
    return (*array)[currentPosition]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
T t = array[currentPosition];
```

is a problem since, type of `array` is `DynamicArray<T>*`. Hence, the type of `array[currentPosition]` is `DynamicArray<T>`.

This should fix it:

```
T t = (*array)[currentPosition];
```